# Can I shadowcopy/backup the AD search index?

Tags: active-directory, disaster-recovery

We have a 1TB+ search index in our Server 2012 Active Directory (6.1) domain. This is located on a NAS, so rebuilding it takes "forever".

For DR purposes, is there a way to correctly back up the search index, so it can be restored without rebuilding? All sources I've found state a rebuild is the right approach in this situation, but we can't afford to take the time to rebuild in a DR situation.

Some ideas we've had were:

- shadowcopy the index
- copy the index folder manually

Both so that we could paste it back in, without rebuilding. We are not advanced AD administrators, so we're hoping someone with more experience can provide practical guidance on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Copying the search index from a backup works as expected.